# Bootstrap datepicker - css styles doesn't load properly?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have input with datepicker, when I click to the input, datepicker won't load as I would expect.
[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwrIC.png)

[And this is how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XEcY.png)

I'm loading bootstrap css and bootstrap datepicker css from CDN - I've also tried load it from PC, but it doesn't work anyways. + also I'm loading bootstrap js, datepicker js and jQuery.
And JS code:

```
    var tdate = new Date();
    $.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';
    $.fn.datepicker.defaults.language = 'en';
    $.fn.datepicker.defaults.startDate = new Date(tdate.getFullYear(), parseInt(mymonth)-1, 1);
    $.fn.datepicker.defaults.endDate = new Date(tdate.getFullYear(), parseInt(mymonth), 0); 
    $.fn.datepicker.defaults.todayBtn = true;
    $.fn.datepicker.defaults.clearBtn = true;
    $.fn.datepicker.defaults.todayHighlight = true;
    $.fn.datepicker.defaults.daysOfWeekDisabled = '0, 6';
    $('.date').datepicker();
```

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle? are you sure you've set the theme name somewhere?

Comment: And what do the dev tools say in the browser?

Comment: Do you mean console? Console is empty. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lucAss/3juceb3r/ now it atleast popup, but you can't close it :( And i forgot to say, that I'm opening datepicker in modal window, but it shouldn't be problem, or?

Comment: Please post a working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].